# How to get last date of particular month from the month ID and year in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How to get last date of particular month from the month ID and year in SQL ?

Inputs :

```
@MonthID INT = 2,
@Year    INT = 2015
```

Required output : `28/02/2015`

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server? As of SQL Server **2012**, there's an [`EOMONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) function for this exact purpose

Comment: Yes its SQL Server 2012 .. Got the answer ..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy in SQL Server 2012+

To frame date from the year and month use **[`DATEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx)**

To find the last day of month use **[`EOMONTH (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx)**

```
Declare @MonthID INT = 2,
        @Year    INT = 2015

SELECT Eomonth(Datefromparts(@Year, @MonthID, 1))
```

For any thing less then `Sql server 2012`

```
SELECT Dateadd(dd, -1, Dateadd(mm, 1, Cast(Cast(@Year AS CHAR(4)) + '-' 
                       + Cast(@MonthID AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+'1' AS DATE)))
```

**Note:** If the variables are of `Varchar` type then you can remove the `cast` to varchar

Answer (score 1):

You can find the last day of the month in the following manner

```
Declare @MonthID varchar(10) = '02', @Year varchar(10) = '2015'
select dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(MM,1,cast(@Year+'-'+@MonthID+'-1' as date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
DECLARE @MonthID INT = 3,
@Year    INT = 2015

DECLARE @InputDate DATE, @TempDate DATE, @OutputDate DATE

SET @InputDate = CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(@MonthID AS varchar) + '-01' AS DATE)
SET @TempDate = @InputDate

WHILE (DATEPART(m, @InputDate) = DATEPART(m, @TempDate))
BEGIN
    SET @OutputDate = @TempDate
    SET @TempDate = DATEADD(d,1,@TempDate)  
END 

SELECT @OutputDate
```